# Python using str as bytearray

Tags: python, byte, arrays

I'm trying to implement a Reed-Solomon encoder.

I start with a list of `bytearray` and then I have to convert all the elements of the list into `str`.

So now I have this list: `["bytearray(b'XXXXXXX')"]`

But I have to retrieve the value from the list: `"bytearray(b'XXXXXXX')"` as a bytearray: `bytearray(b'XXXXXXX')`...

How can I perform this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're doing it right...

If you want to convert all list elements to str, you'd use the `bytearray.decode` method:

```
In [10]: lst = [bytearray(b'XXXXXXX')]

In [11]: newlst = [x.decode('ascii') for x in lst]

In [12]: newlst
Out[12]: ['XXXXXXX']
```

And the reverse of that is

```
In [13]: [bytearray(s, 'ascii') for s in newlst]
Out[13]: [bytearray(b'XXXXXXX')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !   I need to keep the "bitearray(b'XXXX') in the string i'm using. That's why i'm struggling turning it back to bitearray once i converted it to str

Comment: This is a strange requirement, but you can `eval` list elements: `[eval(x) for x in lst]` @FarmerJoe

Comment: Oh thank you @vaultah , i didn't not know `eval`. I'm gonna check how this works !

Comment: Though using `eval` is a bad practice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice I think you've faced the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.